# My URI failed to launch my console app from my web app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, console

I'm trying to open a console app in .NET from my ASP.NET Core MVC web app. In order to open a console app remotely without knowing the path of the file.

I created the key in the editor register, but when I click to launch my app from my web app, the console app fails to launch.

This is my console app code:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

Console.WriteLine("Listening.."); //Gets the current location where the file is downloaded   

var loc = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\Console\"))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Console\");
} //Creates the Downloaded file in the specified folder  

if (!File.Exists(@"C:\Console\" + loc.Split('\\').Last()))
{
    File.Move(loc, @"C:\Console\" + loc.Split('\\').Last());
}

var KeyTest = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software", true).OpenSubKey("Classes", true);
RegistryKey key = KeyTest.CreateSubKey("alert");
key.SetValue("URL Protocol", "wnPing");
key.CreateSubKey(@"shell\open\command").SetValue("", @$"C:\Console\{loc.Split('\\').Last()} %1");
```

In my `index.cshtml`, I have this code with my URI:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <p><a href="alert:wmPing?id=string">Ouvrir dans l'application console</a>.</p>
</div>
```

I have this in my `c:\Console\`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vdai.png)

My console app generates this in my editor register:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuvNo.png)

I get this error when I try to launch my console app with my uri:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrhXa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
Your program is trying to move itself.

You cannot manipulate executable, which is currently executing.

Option 2:
In the destination directory there is already file with given name.